# Seems my pylance having issue with autocomplete third party module's method

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, pylance

I am trying to switch the editor from Pycharm to Vscode somehow.

But some aspect of autocomplete isn't working in vscode I guess.

Specifically, when I want to utilize autocomplete dealing with BeautifulSoup module,

and want to see autocomplete in deeper property,

[image: properly working in Pycharm]

autocomplete works properly in Pycharm, where as vscode,

[image]

shows nothing.

I roughly know it may be a problem with Pylance extrapaths something

but I could'n figure out how.

I tried some features in setting.json like adding python language server to pylance,

or some kinda of pyright plugin hoping more delicate function but didn't get it.

Can I get some direct info about this matter?

Comment: what is the return type of `find_all()`

Comment: it is <class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>, type(a_tags)

Comment: what does PyLance know about a `ResultSet`

Comment: you mean I have to let pylance include the information about the module, right? how?

Comment: PyLance is a static analyzer, it somehow determines `a_tags` is a `ResultSet`, but what does PyLance know about a `ResultSet`, if it is a dynamic type you need Python type files to inform PyLance of the internals of `ResultSet`

Comment: Maybe I lack of enough knowledge for understanding what you explain. Do you intend to ask in need of information to get this figured or you are directing me with your questions to teach me PyLance is not a thing what I expect?

Comment: Excuse me for this. Maybe I didn't get what you said because I'm not a native English. Would you explain to me what I have to do to get it adjusted specifically?

Comment: I don't use BeautifulSoup, PyLance can't show information it doesn't has, if `ResultSet` for PyLance has type `Any` you don't get autocomplete, in such a case you can add to PyLance Python type files, look in the extension, to fill in the blanks PyLance can't deduce from the source code

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for the comment. But I am still struggling to figure out exactly how. :( where is that "PyLance Python type files"? say in case of mac? Is there other ways to deal with it in settings.json in vscode? What should I add exactly in that blanks(what is this exactly?)? Maybe I don't have an idea of what "type for PyLance" is.. bunch of question marks :( Sorry for poor knowledge

Comment: if there is a thread or an article specifically about this matter please let me know of that if u r okay

Comment: you still haven't reported the type of `ResultSet`, search extension for `.pyi` files, you can your own (AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

The [same problem](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/241) exists on github and has been closed.

Beautiful soup needs to add type stubs for this to work.

You could suggest developer updating the package on [bs4](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/).

Comment: Thenk you for the link!